# Changing Dropout value during training

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

How can I change Dropout during training? For example

```
Dropout= [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

I tried passing it as as a list but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the dropout probability during training, you should use the `functional` version, i.e. `torch.nn.functional.dropout`.

The input arguments to the functional version of dropout are

- the input tensor
- the dropout probability (which you can alter)
- a boolean to indicate if it is in training mode (you can use the `self.training`)
- and a flag to indicate if you want the operation to be performed in place.

Thus, you can alter the probability of the dropout in your `forward` method, according to your needs.

For example, you can do in your `forward` method:

```py
def forward(self, x):

    ...

    # apply some layers to the input
    h = self.my_layers(x)

    # set the value of p
    p = self.get_value_for_p()

    # apply dropout with new p
    h = torch.nn.functional.dropout(h, p, self.training)

    ...
```

More on the functional version of dropout, here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#dropout-functions

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to directly access the attribute of the `Dropout` class:

```py
def forward(self, x, p=0.5):
    self.dropout_layer.p = p
    x = self.layers1(x)
    x = self.dropout_layer(x)
    x = self.layers2(x)
    return x
```

Example to show that this works:

```py
layer = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
x = torch.rand()
layer(x) # tensor([0.0680, 0.0000, 1.4633, 6.5492, 0.0000])
layer.p = 0.9
layer(x) # tensor([0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 6.5492, 0.0000])
```